# Array of UIButtons return error

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, ios10

I have an array of `UIButton` objects (I have 5 buttons so I wanted to store them in an array for easy processing). But `Array` give me error

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArray0 addObject:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance"

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *starOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *starTwo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *starThree;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *starFour;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *starFive;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *_starButtons;
```

I have below code in `viewDidLoad` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   self._starButtons=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self._starButtons addObject:self.starOne];
    [self._starButtons addObject:self.starTwo];
    [self._starButtons addObject:self.starThree];
    [self._starButtons addObject:self.starFour];
    [self._starButtons addObject:self.starFive];

 NSLog(@"%@",self._starButtons);
}
```

Please help me where i am going wrong.

Comment: which line are you getting the error at?

Comment: Try changing NSMutableArray property to be strong instead of copy.

Comment: @Imad  I have changed copy to strong it gives me

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: @diksha Could you pls share your storyboard or nib file and show IBOutlet connections

Comment: @Diksha Check connection of IBOutlet

Comment: @Imad I have programmatically create button like


self->starOne=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,15,42,37)];
    [self->starOne setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self->starOne.tag=1;
    
    [self->starOne addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(press_1:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view addSubview:self->starOne];

Comment: @diksha If you've created programmatically then why do have IBOutlet for buttons? In which method you've created those button, please share.

Comment: @diksha can you post the button initialization code snippet along with your question?

Comment: @diksha change `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *_starButtons;` to `@property NSMutableArray *_starButtons;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove `copy` from declaration of array property, make it `strong`.

Second thing as you have said in comment that you have programmatically created buttons then you not need `IBOutlets`. So, remove `IBOutlets` from all properties of button.

Your declaration should like,

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *starOne;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *starTwo;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *starThree;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *starFour;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *starFive;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *_starButtons;
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily the correct solution. The original property used `copy`. Presumably there was a good reason for that. Simply removing `copy` changes the behavior and can lead to difficult to notice bugs.

Comment: as per the code posted in question, I don't think `copy` is required! @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *one;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *two;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *three;
@end
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSMutableArray *buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:one,two,three,nil];
NSLog(@"%@",buttonArray);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Storyboard or Nib file then:

Another approach is to connect the UIButtons' to an `NSArray` of `IBOutletCollection` in Interface Builder, instead of adding manually each button to an `NSMutableArray`. Something like this for all UIButtons'.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttonsArray;
```

[image: Xcode]

Answer (score 0):

Just one change in code.

Replace this line:

```
@property NSMutableArray *_starButtons;
```